# About snapshot feature in Azure App service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, backup

In Microsoft documentation, Microsoft dosen't say what folder is considered by snapshot. But , she say : `any data outside '/home' is not persisted` , when open a ssh terminal on the web app using Kudu.

So, if i have an azure web app custom docker image with `premium` sku , which he run a application stored under `/var/www/html` and this application store log file in `/home/site/wwwroot` ( option `websites_enable_app_service_storage` is already changed to yes )

My question is : when using snapshot to restore web app ,  should i found all content in the web app ? Or only the file stored in /home ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your question was answered in this [Github thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/78653).

Adding to Ajay's answer- Snapshots contain both the contents of a web app and the web app configuration. Your app files content can be found in the D:\home\site\wwwroot folder of your app.

Comment: so , i can find my files in both folder ( /home/site/wwwroot ) and ( /var/www/html) 
thanks